# group array of php objects and sum by object key

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array of php objects that looks something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [order_id] => 1513
        [order_total] => 12500.00
        [sales_rep] => Doe_John
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [order_id] => 1046
        [order_total] => 3300.00
        [sales_rep] => Doe_John
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [order_id] => 337
        [order_total] => 4500.00
        [sales_rep] => Mosby_Ted
    )
)
```

I am trying to get an array that is set up more like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sales_rep] => Doe_John
        [total_sales] => 15800.00
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [sales_rep] => Mosby_Ted
        [total_sales] => 4500.00
    )
)
```

I want to combine all of the objects with the same "sales_rep" and get the sum of their associated "order_total", which you can see an example of in my desired array above. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I've been at it for hours now and have not been able to figure out a solution.

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Can you perhaps use an array where the key is the sales rep and the value is the total sales to simplify lookup?

Comment: Absolutely, I could take it that way as well. That actually isn't a bad idea. Ultimately I was just trying to make a list of sales reps and their total sales sorted by sales descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$tmp = array();
foreach($objs as $obj){ // where `$objs` is your objects
    if(!in_array($obj->sales_rep,array_keys($tmp))){
        $tmp[$obj->sales_rep] = (object)array(
            'sales_rep' => $obj->sales_rep,
            'total_sales' => $obj->order_total
        );
    }else{
        $tmp[$obj->sales_rep]->total_sales += $obj->order_total;
    }
}
print_r(array_values($tmp));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. Now I just need to figure out how to sort by order_total. Appreciate it!

Comment: I switched the order of sales_rep and total_sales so total_sales comes first in the array and just did a `arsort( $tmp );` to sort by total, descending. Worked like a charm. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj0 = new StdClass();
$obj0->order_id = 1513;
$obj0->order_total = 12500.00;
$obj0->sales_rep = 'Doe_John';

$obj1 = new StdClass();
$obj1->order_id = 1046;
$obj1->order_total = 3300.00;
$obj1->sales_rep = 'Doe_John';

$obj2 = new StdClass();
$obj2->order_id = 337;
$obj2->order_total = 4500.00;
$obj2->sales_rep = 'Mosby_Ted';

$array = array(
    $obj0,
    $obj1,
    $obj2,
);

$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
  if (array_key_exists($item->sales_rep, $newArray)) {
      $newObj = $newArray[$item->sales_rep];
      $newObj->order_total += $item->order_total;
  } else {
      $newObj = new StdClass();
      $newObj->sales_rep = $item->sales_rep;
      $newObj->order_total = $item->order_total; 
      $newArray[$newObj->sales_rep] = $newObj;
  }
}

print_r(array_values($newArray));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!